# Internal Server Error Error 500 Codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, hosting, cpanel, namecheap

I'm using namecheap cpanel in hosting my website. I'm having a hard time to load my website. I already changed my config.php base url and database.php. I've already changed the htaccess several times with this code. Can anyone help me as to how i can fix this problem?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
# !IMPORTANT! Set your RewriteBase here and don't forget trailing and 
# slashes.
# If your page resides at
# http://www.example.com/mypage/test1
# then use
# RewriteBase /mypage/test1/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
```

but when i revert the htaccess to this code, it displays 404 error:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: It's look like the coding error

Comment: @DanishAli i updated the question please take a look..

Comment: When you revert the code then page is not getting with `.htaccess`. When `.htaccess` works then it goes to internal server error. So, I think it is not `.htaccess` issue.

Comment: can we talk in skype instead for better understanding of this issue.. @DanishAli